# realtime notifications take very long for certain accounts

Tags: javascript, getstream-io

I'm trying to debug why realtime notifications take a very long time to arrive using the realtime api. Doing the manual data pull works as expected.

I've signed up for a personal getstream account and used those keys, and the notification latency is as expected.

[image: video of getstream realtime notification working as expected]

However, with the exact same code and simply switching out keys with an existing application we have, it takes more than 16 minutes (!!!) to arrive (I'm not attaching a video here since it's huge, but just a screenshot of the time the notification arrived).

[image: screenshot of getstream realtime notification taking more than 16mins before the notification is received]

I can confirm that the data is submitted to getstream via looking at the stream explorer tab in the website and enabling autorefresh.

Here's the sample poc code I've written to illustrate the problem https://github.com/parasquid/getstream_poc/blob/master/views/index.html.erb

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/getstream/dist/js_min/getstream.js"></script>
hello!

<div id="timer"></div>
<p><button id="add-activity">Add activity</button>

<script>
  var interval
  var client = stream.connect('<%= @apikey %>', null,  '<%= @appid %>');

  var userFeed = client.feed('user', '<%= @user_id %>', '<%= @user_token %>')
  var userSubscription = userFeed.subscribe(
    () => userFeed.get()
      .then(streamData => console.log(streamData))
      .then(() => clearInterval(interval)),
    (errors) => console.error({errors})
  );

  var notificationFeed = client.feed('notification', '<%= @user_id %>', '<%= @notification_token %>')
  var notificationSubscription = notificationFeed.subscribe(
    () => notificationFeed.get().then(streamData => console.log(streamData)),
    (errors) => console.error({errors})
  );

  button = document.querySelector("button#add-activity")
  button.onclick = (e) => {
    timer = document.querySelector("div#timer");
    var seconds = 0
    interval = setInterval(() => {
      seconds++;
      timer.innerHTML = seconds;
    }, 1000);

    fetch("/add_activity")
      .then(r => r.json())
      .then(json => console.log(json));
  }

</script>
```

From what I can gather, this seems to be specific to the account rather than the implementation; or maybe I'm just doing something weird. Would appreciate pointers!

---

Update 2019-04-02

I've created another app that mirrors as closely as I can the setup on the other account (just changing the location, as it looks like we need to contact support to change locations for an existing app, and we only use the user and notification feed groups) and while there is definitely more latency, it's not as bad as the original app.

[image: screenshot with app located in singapore]

[image: screenshot of old slow app and new fast app side by side]

Comment: is there any difference in the two apps you are testing? eg. feed groups / region used ...

Comment: the only difference would be location I guess? The slow account's app location is Singapore while the newly created account's app location is us-east.

My local machine is currently located in Malaysia so I would have thought the latencies would be faster.

Good idea, let me see if tweaking the location changes things.

Comment: @TommasoBarbugli I've added more info above. I've tried your suggestion (mirror the feed groups and location) and while there's more latency (11 seconds instead of 1) it's still not as bad as the original app we're using.